# При отсутствии страницы выдавать 404

Tags: http-status-code-404, .htaccess, php, header

Здравствуйте.

Раньше, набирая несуществующую страницу, был редерикт на главную. После чего,
покопавшись в движке и создав 404 страницу, смог настроить отдачу ошибки, но
получилось, что только на каталоги, и остались следующие проблемы со страницами:

**Проблема №1:** При наборе несуществующей страницы, к примеру:
`http://www.nikand.ru/production/fireplaces/3057.htm`
`http://www.nikand.ru/production/fireplaces/30057.htm`
`http://www.nikand.ru/production/fireplaces/300057.htm`
и т.д. открывается страница каталога, но при этом в адресной строке остается несуществующий url и отдает **200** вместо **404**.

**Проблема №2:** При добавлении символов после `.htm` ничего не происходит, страница не
меняется. Примеры:
`http://www.nikand.ru/production/pechi/345.htm1233`
`http://www.nikand.ru/production/pechi/345.htmава`

Нужно, чтобы все несуществующие страницы (как и каталоги) отдавали **404**. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

---

Есть неправильный url вида `http://www.nikand.ru/production/fireplaces/3851.htm`
Необходимо, если я ввожу неправильный url, показывать страницу 404,
если я ввожу правильный url `http://www.nikand.ru/production/fireplaces/385.htm`, показывать товар.

Есть такой код:

```
if(is_int(DOC) && $goodsr['zag']){
    echo "Ok";
}
else if(is_int(DOC) && !$goodsr['zag'])
{ 
    header("Location: error404.php");
    exit();  
}
```

Как проверить, что DOC число, и если товар существует, показывать товар, а если нет - ошибку 404?

Comment: @demonicq2014,  
Какую CMS или framework вы используете?  
Как именно вы смогли настроить отдачу ошибки? Покажите код.

Answer (score 1):

Как проверить, что DOC число, - http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

И если товар существует - проверка на сущестовование в БД, ищите и найдете.

А редирект у Вас уже прописан.

И поддержу [[@VenZell](/users/13336/venzell)](/users/13336/venzell) - что используете-то?

**Обновление**

У Вас в примере прописан `Header("Location");`, но Вы не используете его на странице, отсюда *проблема* **1**, да и **2** тоже.

Код ответа можете отдавать тем же http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php#refsect1-function.header-parameters

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
```